# c++ - Segmentation Fault on Function Call?

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault

I'm trying to create a simple binary search tree class in c++, but whenever I call my insert function:

```
template<typename T>
void BSTree_Fast<T>::insert(T & key)
{
  cout<<"working";
  int i=0;
  BSTNode<T> *newNode=new BSTNode<T>(key);  //Initializing pointer to newNode with key as Key
  if(maxDepth==0){              //if tree is empty, sets root to new node
    root=newNode;
    setMaxDepth(1);
  }
  BSTNode<T> *curr=root;            //Traversal unit curr
  if(key==curr->getKey()){          //checking if inserted key is same as root key
    int n=curr->getNum();
    n++;
    curr->setNum(n);
    delete(newNode);
  }
while(key!=curr->getKey()){         //first while loop when above is not true
  if(key<curr->getKey()){           //checks left if key < current key
    if(curr->getLeft()==NULL){      //if cannot traverse left, creates new node to left of current
        curr->setLeft(newNode);
        if(i>maxDepth){
            cout<<i;
            setMaxDepth(i);
        }
        break;
    }
    else if(curr->getLeft()->getKey()==key){//if left child equals input key, increase number
        int n=curr->getLeft()->getNum();
        n++;
        curr->getLeft()->setNum(n);
        delete(newNode);
        break;
    }
    else{
        i++;
        curr=curr->getLeft();       //traverses left
    }
  }
  if(key>curr->getKey()){           //checks right if key > current key
    if(curr->getRight()==NULL){     //if cannot traverse right, creates new node to right
        curr->setRight(newNode);
        if(i>maxDepth){
            setMaxDepth(i);
        }
        break;
    }
    else if(curr->getRight()->getKey()==key){//if right child equals input key, increase number
        int n=curr->getRight()->getNum();
        n++;
        curr->getRight()->setNum(n);
        delete(newNode);
        break;
    }
    else{
        i++;
        curr=curr->getRight();      //traverses to right
    }
  }
}   
}
```

However it appears to hit a segfault before any of the actual code can be implemented when calling it with a string being read in from a file.

Comment: Output may be line buffered.  Have you tried adding a newline - `<< endl` - to your logging statement at the start of the function?  There are lots of places later in the code that could cause a seg fault (e.g. if `root` is NULL on first insertion).  You'll either need to debug further yourself or provide a full runnable example to get more specific help

Comment: You forgot to ask a question. When you push the `Ask Question` button, you are expected to actually ask a specific question. You told a story and then just stopped, leaving us to guess what your actual question is. It could be anything from "What's a segmentation fault?" to "Does my code look remotely sensible?".

Answer (score 4):

Walk through the process of adding the first node:

```
  BSTNode<T> *newNode=new BSTNode<T>(key);  //Initializing pointer to newNode with key as Key
  if(maxDepth==0){              //if tree is empty, sets root to new node
    root=newNode;
    setMaxDepth(1);
  }
```

Uh oh, there's no `return` here. So after we set `root=newNode`, we go on.

```
  BSTNode<T> *curr=root;            //Traversal unit curr
  if(key==curr->getKey()){          //checking if inserted key is same as root key
    int n=curr->getNum();
    n++;
    curr->setNum(n);
    delete(newNode);
  }
```

Obviously the keys will match. So we just deleted `newNode`, which is also both `root` and `cur`.

```
while(key!=curr->getKey()){
```

Ooops, we access `curr`, which we just deleted.